# How can this perl sub be optimised for speed?

Tags: performance, perl

The following perl sub is used to store arrays of hashes.
Each hash to be stored is first checked for uniqueness using a given key, if a hash exists on the array with the same key value then it's not stored.

How can this perl sub be optimised for speed?

Example use:

```
my @members;
...
$member= {};
$hash->{'name'}='James';
hpush('name', \@members,$member);
```

The sub:

```
sub hpush {
  # push a set of key value pairs onto an array as a hash, if the key doesn't already exist
  if (@_ != 3) {
    print STDERR "hpush requires 3 args, ".@_." given\n";
    return;
  }

  my $uniq = shift;
  my $rarray = shift;
  my $rhash = shift;
  my $hash = ();

  #print "\nHash:\n";
  for my $key ( keys %{$rhash} ) {
    my $valuea = $rhash->{$key};

    #print "key: $key\n";
    #print "key=>value: $key => $valuea\n";
    $hash->{ $key} = $valuea;
  }

  #print "\nCurrent Array:\n";
  for my $node (@{$rarray}) {
    #print "node: $node \n";
    for my $key ( keys %{$node} ) {
      my $valueb = $node->{$key};
      #print "key=>value: $key => $valueb\n";
      if ($key eq $uniq) {
        #print "key=>value: $key => $valueb\n";
        if (($valueb =~ m/^[0-9]+$/) && ($hash->{$key} == $valueb)) {
          #print "Not pushing i $key -> $valueb\n";
          return;
        } elsif ($hash->{$key} eq $valueb) {
          #print "Not pushing s $key -> $valueb\n";
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  push @{$rarray}, $hash;
  #print "Pushed\n";

}
```

Note that the perl isn't mine and I'm a perl beginner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code is rather... not very efficient. First, it copies `$rhash` to `$hash`, with a for loop... for some reason. Then it loops through the hash keys, instead of simply using the hash key that it's looking for. Then it does two equivalent checks, apparently some attempt to distinguish numbers from non-numbers and selecting the appropriate check (`==` or `eq`). This is all unnecessary.

This code below should be roughly equivalent. I've trimmed it down hard. This should be as fast as it is possible to get it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

hpush('name', \@members,$member);

sub hpush { 
    my ($uniq, $rarray, $rhash) = @_;

    for my $node (@{$rarray}) {
        if (exists $node->{$uniq}) {
            return if ($node->{$uniq} eq $rhash->{$uniq});
        }
    }
    push @{$rarray}, $rhash;
}
```

Comment: Are the `==` and `eq` checks equivalent? I seem to remember that one was for numeric comparisons and one for strings? i.e. 05 is numerically the same as 5 but not string-wise. Maybe it doesn't matter given my data.

Comment: NYTProf is coming back as 1.8s rather than 4.6s so it's definitely faster code...

Comment: @Craig I think you must decide based on your data which comparison is best. If you wish, you can put back the numeric test. Something like: `return if ($node->{$uniq} =~ /^[0-9]+$/ and $node->{$uniq} == $rhash->{$uniq});` However, then you would need to beware of numbers that can contain non-numeric characters, such as `12.20` or `FF`.

Comment: Checked against my data set and it's fine. I note there is also a feature called smart matching which attempts to do the correct type of comparison based on the data. [smart matching in detail](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail)

Comment: Smart matching will have the same caveats, except then you will not know exactly what goes on. 05 and 5 will be considered equal with smart matching, for example.